# Making a class process A 2 by 2 Matrix and having issues return it through __str__

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, matrix

so I have to process a 2 by 2 matrix through a class and return print the output with **str**. I can't really create new functions and I'm pretty sure the math is good with the matrices, I'm just having some output issues. I marked the area, specifically really the output that I cannot modify, but I can modify the class to support it.

Here's my code.

```py
# This code aims to take a 2 by 2 matrix and add, subtract, and multiply it by another matrix, as well as inverse and power it.
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This is how we'll use math.nan and only math.nan
import math

# Your classes should go here
class Matrix2x2:  # Just initializing as needed.
    def __init__(self,a,b,c,d):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d

    def __add__(self,second):
        return(Matrix2x2(self.a+second.a,self.b+second.b,self.c+second.c,self.d+second.d))

    def __sub__(self, second):  # Just subtracting instead of adding
        return(Matrix2x2(self.a - second.a,self.b-second.b,self.c-second.c,self.d-second.d))

    def __mul__(self, second):  # Multiplying them based on the according spot and some addition.
        return(Matrix2x2(self.a*second.a+self.b*second.c,self.a*second.b+self.b*second.d,self.c*second.a+self.d*second.c,self.c*second.b+self.d*second.d))

    def __pow__(self, power):  # Process varies based on what we work with.
        StoredMatrix = Matrix2x2(self.a, self.b, self.c, self.d)  # The variables just save information and make the math more clean.
        determinant = 1/((self.a*self.d)-(self.b*self.c))  # Used to simplify inversing and determine if there is an inverse.
        InverseMatrix = Matrix2x2(self.d*determinant,-self.b*determinant,-self.c*determinant, self.a*determinant)
        if power > 0:
            count = 1
            while count < power:  # The original matrix is repeatedly multiplied and stored until it matches the power value.
                count+=1
                StoredMatrix *= Matrix2x2(self.a, self.b, self.c, self.d)
            return StoredMatrix
        elif power < 0:
            count = 0
            while count < power:
                count+=1
                InverseMatrix *= Matrix2x2(self.d*determinant,-self.b*determinant,-self.c*determinant,self.a*determinant)
            return InverseMatrix
        if determinant == 0 or power == 0:  # This means that there is no inverse, or the power value is 0 and invalid.
            return(Matrix2x2(math.nan, math.nan, math.nan, math.nan))

    def __str__(self):
        return print('[',str(self.a) ,str(self.b) ,']\n' ,'\b[' ,str(self.c) ,str(self.d),']')

#  Do NOT use any pre-built packages to perform the below operations, each should
#   be coded using regular mathematics operation (+,-,*,/), no numpy or math functions other
#   than math.nan

# Code below cannot be modified
A = Matrix2x2(1,2,3,4)
B = Matrix2x2(4,3,2,1)

print('Addition: A+B')
print(A,"+\n",B,"=\n",A+B,sep="")
input(),print('Subtraction: A-B')
print(A,"-\n",B,"=\n",A-B,sep="")
input(),print('Multiplication: A*B')
print(A,"*\n",B,"=\n",A*B,sep="")
input(),print('Multiplication: B*A')
print(B,"*\n",A,"=\n",B*A,sep="")
input(),print('Powers: A^3 ')
print(A,"^3","\n=\n",A**3,sep="")
input(),print('Inverse: A^-1 ')
print(A,"^-1","\n=\n",A**(-1),sep="")
input(),print('Inverse with powers: A^-3  = (A^-1)^3')
print(A,"^-3","\n=\n",A**(-3),sep="")
# code above cannot be modified

# Just for testing, below.
print(A.__add__(B))
print(A.__sub__(B))
print(A.__mul__(B))
print(A.__pow__(3))
print(A.__pow__(-1))
print(A.__pow__(0))
print(A.__pow(-3))
```

I usually get an error due a NoneType with the **add** function. This doesn't allow me to see what errors I'd get. I tried just converting them to strings individually using str() and got the same error. I don't think it's the math.nan's either. 
Here is an example:

```py
Addition: A+B
[ 1 2 ]
[ 3 4 ]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ThisWasPurposelyCensored", line 51, in <module>
    print(A,"+\n",B,"=\n",A+B,sep="")
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Anyways, how do I avoid that NoneType issue or get this to be compatible with **str**, without interfering with the math and required input too much? I'll provide anymore information you might need to help me solve this.

Comment: In `def __str__(self)` remove `print(...)` function. Print function returns always `None` - instead, return formatted string.

Comment: `\b` is backspace. Are you sure you want that?

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your `__str__` method to be like this

```
def __str__(self):
    return '[ {} {} ]\n[ {} {} ]'.format(self.a, self.b, self.c, self.d)
```

### A bit shorter

```
def __str__(self):
    return '[ {x.a} {x.b} ]\n[ {x.c} {x.d} ]'.format(x=self)
```

Comment: Well darn, that was pretty simple. It works now, thanks.

Comment: Don't wrap everything in `str`, `{}` already does that for you

Comment: right, I've just copied that from the source code we had :)

Comment: if version doesn't allow f-string, can be also written as: `'[ {x.a} {x.b} ]\n[ {x.c} {x.d} ]'.format(x=self)`